# How to save you terraria data on cloud

Tags: terraria-mobile

I'm using iPad and I do not know how to save terraria iOS on cloud, be specific like settings something then later on, also I was thinking next time do I just need to press cloud save in terraria to save it. Thank you very much and tell me the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create a cloud map, via the create a cloud world feature. You can also create up to three cloud characters.